# Permission to send to a Distribution group

Tags: windows, exchange, windows-server-2012, exchange-2013

I created a dynamic distribution group named "#All" and I would like to allow only some high users to send to this group.

[image]

I know I can add separatly each user into the distribution group from the Exchange admin center, but what I want to achieve is to permit only a security group to send to #All and then I add the users I want into the security group.

I know I can add a distribution group into the allowed senders for #All, but I can't find a way to allow a security group. Is this ever possible? If not what is the best practice for doing what I want to achieve?

Comment: AFAIK security groups (non mail-enabled) can't get any exhchange-related permissions, so you'l need to mail-enable this group (but I think it's not a best-practice).

Comment: You will need to mail enable the group.  But I think the proscription is the other way:  you don't want to make a distribution group be a security group unless needed because that results in more overhead in AD because, for example, the security groups need to replicate to all DCs whereas distribution groups should only be replicating to GCs